# SB raise in preflop in no limit TH

Tags: nlhe, betting-strategy, cash-game, pre-flop

please correct me if I am wrong:

**No Limit Texas Holdem**

5 players at the table. Each has bankroll of $1000. SB = $1. BB = $2.

- Player1 = BTN
- Player2 = SB
- Player3 = BB
- Player4 = UTG1
- Player5 = MP1

Pre-flop.

1. PL2 - sb - $1.
2. PL3 - bb - $2.
3. PL4 - call - $2.
4. PL5 - call - $2.
5. PL1 - call - $2.

NOW:

I assume that if PL1 want to do minimum raise he must do:

PL1 - raise - $4.

and preflop must go another turn.

In poker rules is written: *Minimum raise: In No Limit Hold'em, the raise amount must be at least as much as the previous bet or raise in the same round.*

(On some websites about poker I saw that PL1 must do $5 raise. They say that at first he must put $1 to call and then $4 to raise. I think it is wrong. I do not provide links to that website to avoid spread of potentially incorrect information).

Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you didn't engage any money yet if you call you would do $2 but the minimum amount for a raise there is $4 since the $2 is from the max amount that was bet in the table and the next amount you can place is $2(max bet)+$2(BB).

Answer:$4

Some casino's might have some rules and sometimes they aren't the same as in other casino's.